# rename postgresql database from command line

Tags: command-line, rename, postgresql-9.1, alter

I run this command from a bat-file:

```
start/wait/d "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\" psql.exe --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname alter_db --file ./batch/rename_database.sql
```

And I get this log-error:

> CEST ERROR:  syntax error at or near
>
> "ï»¿ALTER" at character 1 CEST STATEMENT:  ï»¿ALTER DATABASE postgres
>   RENAME TO postgres_old;

rename_database.sql has the following content: ALTER DATABASE postgres RENAME TO postgres_old;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your file `./batch/rename_database.sql` was created with a [unicode byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). `psql` doesn't like this. Remove the BOM and try again.

I quote the linked article:

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.

Comment: Thanks @Craig Ringer! It works - how I got the mark I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1->First of all disconnect from the database that has to be renamed

Step 2-> disconnect all the clients from the database to be renamed

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid )
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid( )
    AND datname = 'db_name_to_be_renamed';
```

Step 3->Then rename the database

```
ALTER DATABASE "db_name_to_be_renamed" RENAME TO "new_db_name";
```

Comment: I can only rename databases if connecting to psql with a user with sufficient rights, and not stating any given database.
The bare "`psql`" command OR `psql -U postgres` should allow renaming your DBs.

Connecting using -U with another user, then changing using 

    set role postgres

doesn't work for me.

Comment: what @user1767316 commented above was the only way I could rename a database causing me troubles in Postgres.